# Jquery Return false (like preventDefault) inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

How do i `return false` inside map function. I am aware that return false inside a loop acts as break.But i need to break and return( to prevent default action)
Here is my code

```
$arr = $( "select.filter_type" )
  $arr.map (i, sel) ->
      val = $(sel).val()

      if (val == "")
        alert("The default action has been prevented")
        return false
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? `map()` doesn't seem appropriate

Comment: Map executes the provided callback on every element of the array (no exceptions).  If you want to break after finding a condition, use a for loop.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that, but i wanted to preventdefault after a certain condition is met. And the answer below seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me

```
 $arr = $( "select.filter_type" )
  $v= false
  $arr.map (i, sel) ->
      val = $(sel).val()

      if ( val == "")
        alert("The default action has been prevented")
        $v= true
        return
  if $v
      return false
```